# Using the map function

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having trouble with the `map` function. When I want to print the created list, the interpreter shows the pointer:

```
>>> squares = map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))
>>> print(squares)
<map object at 0x0000000002A086A0>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that a list is not created. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a specific type of [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) in Python 3 that is not a list (but rather a 'map object', as you can see). You can try

```
print(list(squares))
```

Or just use a list comprehension to obtain a list in the first place (which seems to work better here anyway):

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

---

`map` used to return a list in Python 2.x, and the change that was made in Python 3 is described in [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) section of the documentation:

> - `map()` and `filter()` return iterators. **If you really need a list, a quick fix is e.g. `list(map(...))`, but a better fix is often to use a list comprehension (especially when the original code uses `lambda`)**, or rewriting the code so it doesn’t need a list at all. Particularly tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the function; the correct transformation is to use a regular `for` loop (since creating a list would just be wasteful).

Answer (score 2):

`map` returns an [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), i.e. this is something that can be used to loop over once it's required. To get the actual list, do `print(list(squares))`. Or

```
for a in squares:    
    print(a)
```

This looks strange at first but imagine you have 1mio numbers. If it would create a list right away, you'd need to allocate memory for 1mio elements, even though you may ever only want to look at one at a time. With an iterator, a full list of elements will only be held in memory if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`map()` has changed between Python 2 and 3. In Python 2, `map` would apply a function to the values of an iterable and return a list. In Python 3, `map` returns an iterator that applies the function to the iterated values as you loop over it.

python2:

```
>>> print map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

python3 - map returns an iterator object:

```
>>> print(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))
<map object at 0x7fb4b7c82250>
```

that can be used by anything that consumes iterators, like `list`

```
>>> print(list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use unpacking, like this:

```
>>> [*map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: This is harder to read than `list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))`, but really it should be a list comprehension instead: `[x**2 for x in range(10)]`