# Where is the data store for the python generator?

Tags: python

I refer to [Python : Using the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087544/python-using-the-map-function)  It says "map returns a specific type of generator in Python 3 that is not a list (but rather a 'map object', as you can see). "  That is my understanding too.  Generator object do not contain the values but is able to give you the values when you call it (next()).  So my question is where are those values store ?

I tried the following experiment.

1. create 2 tuple and check their size
2. create 2 map objects from the tuple
3. do a next() on the map objects to use up some of the values
4. delete one of the tuple
5. continue to do next()

I would assume that when I delete the tuple, there would be no more values to do a next() but that's not the case.  So my question is where are those values coming from ?  Where are they stored after I delete the tuple ?

Code:

```
t1 = tuple(range(1000))
t2 = tuple(range(10000))
print(f'{t1[:10]} len = {len(t1):5d} size = {getsizeof(t1):5d}')
print(f'{t2[:10]} len = {len(t2):5d} size = {getsizeof(t2):5d}')
```

Output:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) len =  1000 size =  8040
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) len = 10000 size = 80040
```

Code:

```
m1 = map(lambda y: print(y), t1)
m2 = map(lambda y: print(y), t2)
print(f'size of m1 = {getsizeof(m1)}')
print(f'size of m2 = {getsizeof(m2)}')
```

Output:

```
size of m1 = 48
size of m2 = 48
```

Do the following a number of  times:

```
next(m1)
next(m2)
```

Output:

```
23
23
```

Delete the tuple:

```
import gc
del t1
gc.collect()
t1
```

Output:

```
168
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-336-df561a5cc277> in <module>
      2 del t1
      3 gc.collect()
----> 4 t1

NameError: name 't1' is not defined
```

Continue next()

```
next(m1)
next(m2)
```

Output:

```
31
31
```

I'm still able to get values from map after deleting the tuple.

Comment: You're not deleting the tuple.

Comment: Generators don't "store" the values. They store the start and stop of the operation. Then each time you call them they will calculate the next value but they also simultaneously forget the previous value.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Thanks for your reply.  So the tuple is still there and being referenced by the map object ?  And thus I can still get the values from it ?   Is my understanding now correct ?

Comment: None of these are generators (a specific type of Python function using `yield` or a short-hand made with a generator expression); `map` makes an iterator, not a generator.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim I think you are refering the to the Range object ?

Comment: And to be clear, `sys.getsizeof` does not do in-depth memory use computations. It's telling you how much the `map` object itself consumes, it doesn't recurse to get the memory consumed by the things it holds references to (it couldn't even if it wanted to, `map` doesn't expose that information).

Comment: @EBDS Not directly. When the `map` object gets created, it creates an iterator for/from the tuple, and stores a reference to that iterator. And that iterator in turn has a reference to the tuple.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, I also confused by this.  I also read that the generator is a function with a yield.  But I also read in different places (as in the question I've quoted) that others are also generator (the question refering to map).  So does it mean the map object contains the values ?

Comment: @EBDS: People misuse generator when they mean iterator. They're *mostly* the same when all you do is iterate them, but generators have extra features (the ability to `send` values into them and inject exceptions), and are generally defined by using `yield` (implicitly in the case of genexprs).

Comment: And yes, the `map` object, internally, is storing it's own owned reference to the `lambda` and the result of calling `iter(t1)` to get an iterator from `t1` (in case `t1` is iterable, but not an iterator); the iterator of a `tuple` will in turn store a reference to the original `tuple`. It has to, otherwise it couldn't resume producing values each time it produced a new one and froze awaiting the next request.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think I understand what you are saying.  It will take some time for me to digest. I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Appreciate all the comments.  I've done another experiment using a list instead.  I amended a value in the list half way through.  And yes, the next() did return the amended value.  This confirms that the map object IS getting values from the list.  And my initial misunderstanding is that the del will delete the tuple and this is wrong.  Going back to basics, it delete the variable which reference the tuple.  Thanks everybody for helping me clear this up.

Comment: FYI, I fixed the terminology in the referenced answers. ("generator" -> "iterator")

Comment: @ShadowRanger Why "(in case t1 is iterable, but not an iterator)"? Does it really make that distinction?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I have come across somebody saying there is a difference between iterator and iterable.  But I cannot remember the exact difference, that's why after reading ShadowRanger's comment, I need to revise and digest.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode found it...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtmiYo_600M  iterable vs iterator.

Comment: Yes, there's absolutely a difference. I just don't think `map` treats them differently. Ostensibly it calls `iter` on *both* of them, and in reality, on *none* of them.

Comment: @wjandrea was it you who earlier asked me to remove the inserted pic and provided a list of links to format the codes ?  I came back to it but it was deleted.  Could please post the links again ?  Thanks.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: It calls it on both of them, it's just the C version of `iter()` (`PyObject_GetIter`). For iterators, that just returns the same iterator (`iter(iterator) is iterator` is required to be true for correctly implemented iterators; it makes it safe to make any iterable, including existing iterators, into an iterator without worrying if it's already an iterator), for iterables, it returns a new iterator over the iterable that the iterable created for you.

Comment: @EBDS Sure, I think it was this: *[Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del` doesn't remove the tuple from memory, it just removes the variable.

The `map` object has its own reference to the tuple -- it's a class instance variable variable.

Garbage collection doesn't remove a the tuple from memory until all references to it are destroyed. This will happen when the generator reaches the end (it should delete its own reference to avoid a memory leak) or if you delete the reference to the generator.

Comment: What "generator" are you talking about? What the OP is calling one doesn't keep the current position in the tuple.

Comment: How does it know which element of the tuple to return next?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. But to perhaps answer yours: If you mean the `map` object - it doesn't.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode The current state of the iteration has to be stored somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I mean the `map` object. I guess it's an iterator, not a generator, although for most purposes I don't think the distinction is significant.

Comment: Yes, in the `tuple_iterator` that `map` gets from the tuple and then uses. But the `map` object has no idea of the `tuple_iterator`'s internals and that there even is something like a "position".

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: We're really getting into implementation details. All those objects work together to implement the map generator.

Answer (score 3):

With `del t1` you delete the *variable*, not the object it references.

Before `del t1`:

[image: before]

After `del t1`:

[image: after]

So that's still all alive and well and functional. You just don't have the separate `t1` variable referencing the tuple anymore.